# To detect BLAST matches within target region or outside

Tags: output, sequence, blast

There,
I will take a piece of DNA sequence from a target sequence site, use it to blast against a genome. Then from blast result output, I want to know if there is any match sequence from other region in addition to match the target site. How to know from the BLAST output? Are there any indicators for the genome site? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You can inspect the blast output for regions with 100% match (or another cut-off).
- Then check if the matched regions are close to the total length of the query sequence.
- If you have more than one hit passing these parameters then you can figure out if they match different regions of your genome by inspecting the matching scaffold and start and end coordinates of the matched regions.